Sometime i got and question mark sign in package name of springboot project
You can see that there is a question mark sign which is displaying in the the package file name.What does it means?and also there are other sign that are displaying like asterisk and the "+" sign also. what does they represent?

I want to know about why that sign is there and what it is indication?

That is from Git or a different version control. ? indicates a local file that has neither been added nor ignored yet.

These signs typically represent different states or statuses related to the files or the version control system (VCS) integrated with your project.
  Question Mark (?): Untracked or new files not yet added to version control.
  Asterisk (*): Modified files that have changes not yet committed.
  Plus (+): Newly added files that are staged for commit.
